# Is it possible to start the phone without pressing power button?

Tags: android, root

I have an app which is running on an android device which has no battery. It's just charging all the time and the app is running. But sometimes the device is not charging and logical to that the phone will turn off.

When it's charging again the device should start from itself and boot. The user shouldn't press the power button. That's the requirement.

Is this possible anyway?

Can I achieve this when I root the device?

Has anybody experiences with that case?

Comment: How can you tell it to start itself if the phone isn't on/running anything. It sounds unlikely.

Comment: yes that was also my thoughts. but maybe root the device and "tells" him when he gets power it should boot the device.

Comment: You may set an **System Alarm**, it will surely fire even if the device is switched off. It will start the phone at that time to fire Alarm.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer, and how can I set it? Do you have a link or something?

Comment: go to your device's menu and search for **S Planner** application. It should allow you to set it.

Comment: @Vigbyor I assume he means from his own code. I cannot find any documentation to back up your claim. Though am intrigued to hear if it is possible.

Comment: Does an AlarmManager solve my problem? like this: http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/

Comment: @silvia_aut My guess is that it is not possible. An alarm manager will run at a given time, or if the device has been off when the alarm should go off, will run when it is turned on. But will not turn the device on to achieve this. At least that is my understanding

Comment: @Doomsknight, that's why I bold format the word **System Alarm**. Not the code AlarmManager class.

Comment: @Vigbyor, but i dont find such a application on my app. I don't know exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: @Vigbyor Do you have a link to this System Alarm class? The reason i mentioned `alarmManager` is because silvia asked if it was possible with such.

Comment: @silvia_aut, there might be different name in your device.

Comment: @Doomsknight, I dont have, by System Alarm class means the way we set alarms in the mobile with our hands, not by code. You know like we add contact, same as we can set Alarm for eg. a birthday alarm.

Answer (score 2):

in short: No.

ADB is not running when the phone is powered off, and as @langerhans said, wake on alarm is proprietary

You could do a hardware solution where you hijack the battery pins to a power station or modified charger. (make sure you do not feed any power through usb at the same time)
It should be cheap and quite easy to build.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is not possible. It is highly device dependant. Some devices allow alarms turning on the phone to ring as an alarm clock even if they are turned off. But this is a proprietary feature and therefore not easily accesible to custom applications.

I have basically the same problem running an Odroid device which luckily turns itself on after power loss, but if I shut it down manually, I can only turn back on with pulling the power.

The only thing I could think off would be an extra watchdog device, but I have no idea if something like that exists. Maybe you'd need to build it yourself.